# compare date and time in PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to insert datetime values into my DB but when i execute my query the inserted values is:
"1970-01-01 00:00:17"
but when i insert date i get the date that was inserted by the user.
this is where i convert the time:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$_POST["date"])));
$s_time =date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$_POST["s_time"]);
$e_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$_POST["e_time"]);
$result = $dbF -> InsertNewEvent($manager,$sport,$date,$s_time,$e_time,$place,$lon,$lat,$event_type,$gen,$min_age,$max_p,$sched);
```

and this is the query:

```
function InsertNewEvent($manager,$sport,$date,$s_time,$e_time,$place,$lon,$lat,$event_type,$gen,$min_age,$max_p,$sched){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, "INSERT into event(manager_id,kind_of_sport,event_date,start_time,end_time,address,longtitude,latitude,private,gender,min_age,max_participants,current_participants,scheduled,event_status)
         VALUES ('$manager','$sport','$date','$s_time','$e_time','$place','$lon','$lat','$event_type','$gen','$min_age','$max_p','1','$sched','1')") or die (mysqli_error($this->con));
    return $result;
}
```

why i get this values?

Comment: that's a bad design. what if you have something start at 11pm, and finish at 1am? you'll end up with an end_time SMALLER than the start_time. you should be using datetime fields for both, then you can have `2015-11-18 23:00:00` -> `2015-11-19 01:00:00` and compare them directly

Comment: I don't understand why you have 1 date and 2 times instead of 2 datetimes.. what will happen if the end_time is after midnight ?

Comment: yes you are right... now i figure that. i will change it.

Comment: no its string i send it from my android application.

Comment: What does the value look like? Will you print it out and include it in your question? Does it look like `2015-11-18 10:35:00` or `1447861434`?

Comment: how can i do what i did in my $date parameter? i would like to get $date into the $s_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change my code to this one and it was resolved thanks.

```
$s_time =$date." ".$_POST["s_time"];
$e_time = $date." ".$_POST["e_time"];
$s_time =date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($s_time));
$e_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($e_time));
```